Area Vector of a flat region
I don't understand the answers provided in the following problem (by the professor)
Let $\vec{v}=\vec{i}+8\vec{j}-7\vec{k}$ and S be the Rectangular region with the orientation shown below.
a) Find a normal vector to the plane in the Upward Direction.
In order to do this, I first found from the given points the equation of the plane which was $2y+z-4=0$. Then using the formula $\vec{n} = \pm (A,B,C)/ \sqrt {A^2+B^2+C^2}$ I found the possible unit normal vectors to be $\vec{n}=\pm (0,\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}})$. However, according to the given answers, the correct answer is considered to be $\vec{n}= (0,\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt{5}})$. Why is this the case? Why is $\vec{n}=(0,\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}})$ incorrect? How can the selection of the positive or negative normal vector be explained by the upward direction asked in this case?
b) Find the area vector.
According to the theory, the area vector is $\vec{A}=\vec{n}A$ where $A$ is the area ofthe region. In this case, we have a rectangle whose width is $2$ and length is $2\sqrt{5}$, as seen in the figure, which means its Area is $4\sqrt{5}$. So, considering the answer provided in the previous question, the area vector would be $\vec{A}= (0,-8,-4)$. However, the accepted answer is given to be $\vec{A}=(0,8,4)$. What am I missing?

I agree with you on part $a)$ and consider the provided answer to be incorrect. The figure clearly shows that the normal vector $\hat{n}$ should have a positive $z$-component to encode the desired orientation of the surface. Moreover, this is consistent with the instructions to find the normal vector pointing in the "upward" direction. This means $\hat{n}=+\left(0,\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)$ for $a)$ and $\vec{A}=4\sqrt{5} \hat{n} = (0,8,4)$ for $b)$. The provided answers are not consistent because the $z$-components of $\hat{n}$ and $\vec{A}$ are of opposite sign. I suspect that the normal vector in the "downward" direction (negative $z$ component) was erroneously written as the solution to part $a)$.

you probably meant to write $\vec{A}=(0,8,4)$, right?

Yes, thank you for catching that.

DarkLord0fPhysics seems to be partly right.
Let $A(2,2,0)$, $B(0,2,0)$, $C(0,0,4)$ and $D(2,0,4)$ be the counter clockwise array of vertices.
a) By right-hand rule, an upward normal vector is $\vec{AB}\times\vec{AD}=\langle0,8,4\rangle$. We can normalize to find the unit normal vector.
b) The area of rectangle is $||\vec{AB}\times\vec{AD}||=\sqrt{8^2+4^2}=4\sqrt5.$

that's what I did first as well. However, I got confused since upward is pretty much the same as outward and was considering if the negative of the unit normal had to be considered.

@Toniiiic Maybe it is (their) intrepretation.
